# CSS Keyframes fade in HOLD and fade out

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

Whats a simple way to fade in, HOLD for a few sec, and fade out.  Code here fades in nice, just not sure how to hold.

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow_case"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow_case {
   width: 100%;
   height: 20vh;
   opacity: 0;
   animation-delay: 1s;
   -webkit-animation: arrowInOut 4s linear forwards;
   animation: arrowInOut 4s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrowInOut {
   0%,100% {opacity: 0;}
   50% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes arrowInOut {
   0%,100% {opacity: 0;}
   50% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Also would like a few sec delay before it starts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code a little bit to get fade in , hold and fade out effect. here is your modified code.

```
.arrow_case {
 width: 100%;
 height: 20vh;
 opacity: 0;
 animation-delay: 1s;
 -webkit-animation: arrowInOut 8s linear forwards;
 animation: arrowInOut 8s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrowInOut {
 0%,100% {opacity: 0;}
 30%, 80% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes arrowInOut {
 0%,100% {opacity: 0;}
 30%, 80% {opacity: 1;}
 }
```

Comment: Hope you got the idea why it worked so that you can exploit it to get your desired effect.

Comment: Yep Im customizing now. . . Keyframes always seem a little non-intuitive to me!

Comment: "Keyframes always seems a little non-intuitive to me!" may be but it is often more   reliable than other JavaScript based solutions.